# Qt: How to fit content to QScrollArea

Tags: qt, resize, widget, qscrollarea

I reimplement a `QScrollArea` and I want to add several widgets to it at runtime. The problem is, till the scrollbars are shown the content of the `QScrollArea` doesn't fit to it. Only if I add more widgets so the scrollbars shown the content fits correctly.

I already tried this after adding widgets

```
this->widget()->resize(this->widget()->sizeHint());
```

or

```
this->widget()->adjustSize();
```

But this doesn't worked. What I have to do to resize the content? Why the content fits after the scrollbars appear?

Comment: check `widgetResizable` property and its description

Comment: Thanks for you answer but this property is set on true already

Comment: Okay, check `sizeAdjustPolicy` inherited from `QAbstractScrollArea` class

Comment: Sry I'm not sure what are you meaning. How can a function from QAbstractScrollArea inherited from QAbstractScrollArea? Could you specify your point a little bit pls?

Comment: You use QScrollArea. Its inherited from QAbstractScrollArea

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an appropriate layout to your scroll area before setting a widget.
2. Set the size constraints(min and max property ) of the widgets being added
3. I am not sure about your widget layout inside the scroll area, but you can make use of spacers to align the widgets ( when initially  there are not many widgets to fill the scroll area for the scroll bar to appear)